# How to remove the apparently un-removable input type="search" border in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, input, border

I've tried quite a bit of stuff... but the border just won't go away. Works fine if you were to replace type="search" with type="text", but I'd hope that's not what I'm required to do.

I'm trying to kill it with

```
input{
    background:transparent;
    border:0;
    border-color:transparent;
    outline:none;
    width:150px;
}​
```

but none of them seem to do the job.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kf9Mu/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apparently Webkit has a custom style for search input fields. You can get rid of it directly then apply your own borders. I removed it here and gave it a red border.

```
input{
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kf9Mu/7/

I've only looked at this in Chrome.

Comment: The default value of -webkit-appearance for text inputs is "textfield"

Comment: I had this issue also, but found out that removing Bootstrap's "built-in" class named "form-control" fixed it...

Comment: Any way to remove the shadow that appears when clicked as well?

Comment: @Akiva you should be able to do what Yassir suggested. `input:focus` `outline: none;`

Comment: @ShaneO'Connor Yeah that worked, and then I realized I also had overwriting css files.

Answer (score 4):

You should try

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

Also see http://37signals.com/svn/posts/2609-customizing-web-forms-with-css3-and-webkit

Comment: Thanks for the link :) Unfortunate for you @Shane O'Connor beat you by a minute and a half with an equally fine answer

Comment: @2unco: I learned something myself while solving your question, so nothing unfortunate here :) By the way, I found the solution with [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools) by looking at the CSS rules from the user agent stylesheet matching the search field.

Comment: Yea, I didn't know Webkit did that, but I found it using the Chrome Developer Tools as well. It does seem like a strange choice on their part.

Comment: I did look there, but just got confused when it 'agreed' that border:0 and still displayed one

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
input:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't help, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

dont't forget about `-webkit-user-select: none;`